# TF400030 Visual Studio Error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

After installing Visual Studio 2015, but while using Visual Studio 2013 I usually get this error message:

[image]

Before this error message, visual studio tries to check out some of my source controlled item in my solution, using TFS on Visual Studio Online.

It takes ages from the check in start until this message is shown. I believe that the error occurs after some kind of timeout.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe the local repository is locked by VS 2013 ? what happens if you first close VS2013 and then try to open VSonline ?

Answer (score 5):

The TF400030 error always occurs when two systems want to access data in the local workspace at the same time.

Please check the **reduce the frequency of this error or avoid it** part in this blog for the idea how to deal with it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2013/05/31/tf400030-the-local-data-store-is-currently-in-use-by-another-operation.aspx

Comment: Thing is, this problem started after installing final release of VS 2015. Before that I had the 2015 RC and was also used to open multiple VS2013 instances with no occurrence of this problem.

Comment: @IgorKondrasovas, working with multiple VS instances is one possible reason which may lead to this error. And does your workspace contains so many items?

Comment: Projects are relatively small. Very far from the limits mentioned in the referenced article above. The strange thing is that I never experienced this problem with multi VS2013 BEFORE VS2015 installation.

Comment: That link is broken, but it can be found here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/phkelley/tf400030-the-local-data-store-is-currently-in-use-by-another-operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/phkelley/tf400030-the-local-data-store-is-currently-in-use-by-another-operation)

Answer (score 1):

maybe local workspace not have enough Space, you can reduce hard drive [local workspace].
I had this problem so I Deleted Many File and reduce my hard drive,so solved this problem easily.